# Create a singleton service without needing to inject it in Angular 7

Tags: angular, service, singleton

## Situation

I've been trying to find a way where I can instantiate a service that will purely sit "in the background" and listen to events (and do stuff) - which I would like to be created when the app initializes, and be forgotten about.

Unfortunately, I would need to use dependency injection into a component, for the service to be instantiated - most paths I take lead to using the `AppComponent`'s constructor.

I won't be directly interacting with the service though (calling methods/properties), and want to keep it out of other components/services which don't have anything directly to do with it.

---

## The service

The service and the logic in it is pretty straightforward. My service is based on a [Dynamic page titles in Angular 2](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/dynamic-page-titles-angular-2-router-events) tutorial.

The service will listen to `NavigationEnd` events from the `Router`, grab the `ActivatedRoute`, and then use the route's data to set the page title.

Unlike the example in the tutorial, I've created my own service instead of putting the logic within the `AppComponent`; I want to keep my separation of concerns tip-top.

page-title.service.ts:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationEnd, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { filter, map, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class PageTitleService {

  constructor(
    router: Router,
    activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    titleService: Title
  ) {
    router.events
      .pipe(
        filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
        map(() => activatedRoute),
        map((route) => {
          while (route.firstChild) {
            route = route.firstChild;
          }

          return route;
        }),
        filter((route) => route.outlet === 'primary'),
        mergeMap((route) => route.data)
      )
      .subscribe((routeData) => titleService.setTitle(routeData['title']));
  }

}
```

Obviously, the service itself will rely on dependency injection to use the `Router`, `ActivatedRoute`, and `Title` services.

---

## The problem

The only way I currently know to instantiate this service is to use dependency injection into another component/service.

E.g. in `app.component.ts`:

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    pageTitleService: PageTitleService, // inject the service to instantiate it
    // ... other services
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // do stuff with other services, but not the pageTitleService
  }

}
```

The problem is, I want to avoid doing this if at all possible.

---

## Question

Is it possible to instantiate the service somewhere other than a component/service?

---

## Possibility?

I do have an `app-load.module.ts`, which does some upfront initialization, before the rest of the app is loaded:

```js
import { APP_INITIALIZER, NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { OrganisationService } from './core/organisation/organisation.service';

export function initApp(organisationService: OrganisationService) {
  return () =>
    organisationService
      .initialize()
      .then(() => window.document.documentElement.classList.remove('app-loading'));
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [],
  declarations: [],
  providers: [
    OrganisationService,
    { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: initApp, deps: [OrganisationService], multi: true }
  ]
})
export class AppLoadModule { }
```

Could I perhaps instantiate the `PageTitleService` in here, somewhere?

Or, is there a better place/way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

### Solution

What you need is a `Class`, which you can use to update page title [or some other stuff], but it should not be injectable.

You can define a plain JS `Class` **`Not as @injectable`**. You can then use the [APP_INITIALIZER](https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER) to instantiate the class manually. The instance thus created will not be accessible using DI, but can be saved and shared by using global/static variable.

Here is the sample [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-ng-app-init-service?file=src/app/app.module.ts). I have only logged to console, you can update as needed.

`TitleService` Class that updates title using `updateTitle` method. 
`PageTitleService` Class that will subscribe to router and calls  `TitleService.updateTitle`. 
`pageTitleServiceInit` factory function to manually instantiate `PageTitleService`.

### Code

```js
import { APP_INITIALIZER, Injectable, NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { HelloComponent } from "./hello/hello.component";
import {
  ActivatedRoute,
  NavigationEnd,
  Router,
  RouterModule
} from "@angular/router";
import { RandomComponent } from "./random/random.component";
import { filter } from "rxjs/operators";

// ================ TitleService ======================
@Injectable()
export class TitleService {
  updateTitle(title: string) {
    console.log("new title: ", title);
  }
}

// ================ Initalizer Factory ======================
function pageTitleServiceInit(router, route, titleService) {
  return () => {
    new PageTitleService(router, route, titleService);
  };
}

// ================ PageTitleService ======================
export class PageTitleService {
  constructor(
    router: Router,
    activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    titleService: TitleService
  ) {
    router.events
      .pipe(filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
      .subscribe((x: any) => {
        console.log(activatedRoute);
        titleService.updateTitle(x.url);
      });
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: "random", component: RandomComponent },
      { path: "hello", component: HelloComponent }
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent, HelloComponent, RandomComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [
    TitleService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: pageTitleServiceInit,
      deps: [Router, ActivatedRoute, TitleService],
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just an observation why injecting in a component (App component) would not be such a bad idea:

1. Showing title in the browser window is a Application requirement and app component is actually the container (or root) your application.
2. So can't we say that it is a concern of application (app component) to have the title updated promptly?
3. A service as i understand can be seen as a helper and App component can use this service to update the title
4. You can have a `init` method in the service which will be called from app component so that it can start listening to router event and update the title. This makes it very imperative, explicit too and you can move calling this init method to some other component if required.

Comment: Though I agree, this is not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution**

Instead of injecting the service via your `app.component.ts`, you could inject the service via the `app.module.ts` (or via your `app-load.module.ts`)

**Eg:**

```
@NgModule({
  ...
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(pageTitleService: PageTitleService) {}
}
```

Comment: This seems to create a unit testing nightmare, as the DI service(s) are created in such a way that you cannot easily mock them out globally. Instead, literally every .spec.ts file would have to mock the services in their configureTestingModule() call, which is onerous on a large project even if you could create a utility function for it. In my case, I need to establish a WS connection on app load, so not mocking the services isn't really an option

Answer (score 1):

I think there are a few options possible.

1. Simply create an instance yourself.
   An service is noting more than a regular class. You can create an instance yourself `new PageTitleService(router, activatedRoute, pageService)` However, this requires you to pass an instance of the objects defined in the constructor.
2. Use the injector. You can call `injector.get(PageTitleService)` to get an instance. Unfortunately injector is also a service which should be inejcted in an component or service.

In your case, you are going to need dependency injection. You could try option 1 and also manually create instances of router and activatedRoute, but they might have their own dependencies. And their dependencies might also have dependencies.

You could create a regular Singleton which has some kind of init function that does al the initial work. Something like this:

```
class Singleton
{
  private constructor()
  {
    console.log("hello");
  }

  private hasStarted = false;

  private static _singelton :Singleton
  static get(): Singleton{
    return Singleton._singleton || (Singleton._singleton = new Singleton())
  }

  pubic init(router: Router, activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, titleService: Title): void{
    if(!hasStarted){
      //do whatever you want
      hasStarted = true;
    }
  }
}
```

In your appcomponent:

```
constructor(router: Router, activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, titleService: Title){
  Singelton.getInstance().init(router: Router, activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, titleService: Title);
}
```

This way there will only be one instance of your singleton an everyting in the init will only be executed once.

Note: nothing is realy private in typescipt. Something like this is still possible.

```
const singleton = Singelton.getInstance();
singelton['hasStarted'] = false;
singleton.init(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [APP_INITIALIZER](https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER) or [APP_BOOTSTRAP_LISTENER](https://angular.io/api/core/APP_BOOTSTRAP_LISTENER). More details you can find [here](https://blog.angularindepth.com/hooking-into-the-angular-bootstrap-process-36e82a01fba8).

For use `Router` in `APP_INITIALIZER` set [initialNavigation](https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions#initialNavigation) option to `true`. Or use `APP_BOOTSTRAP_LISTENER` (but you skip first navigation in this case)

for add initalizer you need add provider for it

```
{
  provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
  useFactory: (router) => yourFunction,
  multi: true,
  deps: [Router]
}
```

Comment: Hi @izmaylovdev, thanks for your answer. While I'm always grateful for helpful links to articles, links can go dead over time - probably not the most useful for future visitors. Also, in SO's guidelines it discourages link-only answers. Could you expand a little on your answer, so I and other users can quickly refer to some useful information from those links?

Answer (score -1):

Is it possible for you to create a `title.ts` in your root folder and do:

```
export const titleConfig = {
  title: '',
}
```

and access that object from whenever you need it, and change it in your router

```
import { titleConfig } from 'src/app/title';
// ...more magic goes here

export class PageTitleService {

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private titleService: Title
  ) {
    this.router.events
      .filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
      .map(() => this.activatedRoute)
      .map((route) => {
        while (route.firstChild) {
          route = route.firstChild;
        }

        return route;
      })
      .filter((route) => route.outlet === 'primary')
      .mergeMap((route) => route.data)
      .subscribe((routeData) => titleConfig.title = routeData['title']); // change here
  }

}
```

if you are using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.Onpush` then you can do a `{ ...routerData['title'] }` or add a `setTitle` method to the object. I'm not sure.